# Pairwise partial correlation of a matrix, controlling by one variable

Tags: r

I have a 100-column table for which I would like to run pairwise partial correlations, controlling by the 100th column's variable using the `pcor.test` function from the `ppcor` package. Is there any partial correlation function in R that I can use the returns something like `rcorr`, taking the pairwise correlations of the whole matrix but only controlling by one variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like for an n-column matrix you want to output a (n-1) x (n-1) matrix of the pairwise correlations of the first n-1 columns, controlling for the last (using the `pcor.test` function from the `ppcor` package).

You could do this with the `sapply` function, looping through each column and computing its correlation to all other columns with `pcor.test`:

```
# Sample dataset with 5 columns
set.seed(144)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=5)

# Compute the 4x4 correlation matrix, controlling for the fifth column
library(ppcor)
sapply(1:(ncol(dat)-1), function(x) sapply(1:(ncol(dat)-1), function(y) {
  if (x == y) 1
  else pcor.test(dat[,x], dat[,y], dat[,ncol(dat)])$estimate
}))
#              [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
# [1,]  1.000000000 -0.01885158 0.06037621 0.004032437
# [2,] -0.018851576  1.00000000 0.09560611 0.097152907
# [3,]  0.060376208  0.09560611 1.00000000 0.105123093
# [4,]  0.004032437  0.09715291 0.10512309 1.000000000
```