# How to perform partial correlation analysis among multiple columns and controlling by multiple covariates?

Tags: r, correlation, sapply

I want to **perform partial correlation analysis among multiple columns controlling by multiple covariates**, and then **extract r and p-value**. **My real data have some missing values**.

I found that this answer ([Pairwise partial correlation of a matrix, controlling by one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198968/pairwise-partial-correlation-of-a-matrix-controlling-by-one-variable)) might be useful, so I adjusted this method into my code. Because I have missing values, so I cannot use `ppcor::pcor.test()`, which is described as '**Missing values are not allowed**', to achieve my goal.

Here I use the built-in dataset `mtcars` to display the problem I met.

```
# load "ggm" packages to perform partial correlation analysis
library(ggm)

# subset mtcars dataset and make some datapoints as missing values
mydata <- cbind(mtcars[1:8])
mydata[4:10,3] <- rep(NA,7)
mydata[1:5,4] <- NA

# perform partial correlation analysis among the first 6 columns with the last two columns as covariates
sapply(1:(ncol(mydata)-2), function(x) sapply(1:(ncol(mydata)-2), function(y) {
  if (x == y) 1
  else ggm::pcor(c(mydata[,x], mydata[,y], mydata[,7], mydata[,8]),var(mydata))
}))

# error:
Error in S[u, u] : subscript out of bounds
```

I got error at this step and could neither perform partial correlation nor extract r and p-values.

Many thanks to you to help me!

Ella

Comment: It seems that `ggm::pcor` function just drop the column containing missing values. Does anyone know which function that can perform partial correlation analysis would delete the rows with missing values rather than dropping the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass the column values in `pcor` function. You can pass column number or column names. Try :

```
sapply(1:(ncol(mydata)-2), function(x) sapply(1:(ncol(mydata)-2), function(y) {
   if (x == y) 1
   else ggm::pcor(c(x, y,7,8),var(mydata))
}))

#           [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#[1,]  1.0000000 -0.7208025   NA   NA  0.5717984 -0.8260219
#[2,] -0.7208025  1.0000000   NA   NA -0.6969510  0.7414846
#[3,]         NA         NA    1   NA         NA         NA
#[4,]         NA         NA   NA    1         NA         NA
#[5,]  0.5717984 -0.6969510   NA   NA  1.0000000 -0.5510354
#[6,] -0.8260219  0.7414846   NA   NA -0.5510354  1.0000000
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you, @Ronak Shah. It seem that `pcor` function just drop the column containing missing values, rather than deleting the row containing missing values.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Would you direct me how to get p-value? Thank you!